# How do I make an unordered_set of shared_ptr objects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am using Visual Studio 2012. When I try this:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<A>> myset;
```

I get this error:

> error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

According to the standard and this error report (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/734888#tabs) this should compile and Microsoft has implemented support in VC++11. So why doesn't this work?

**EDIT:** HOW do I make this work? I have tried the workaround on the linked page and it simply gives me an error saying that the hash function has already been defined. Sure enough, on line 1803 of the "memory" file in the VC directory there is this:

```
template<class _Ty>
    struct hash<shared_ptr<_Ty> >
        : public unary_function<shared_ptr<_Ty>, size_t>
    {   // hash functor
    typedef shared_ptr<_Ty> _Kty;
    typedef _Ty *_Ptrtype;

    size_t operator()(const _Kty& _Keyval) const
        {   // hash _Keyval to size_t value by pseudorandomizing transform
        return (hash<_Ptrtype>()(_Keyval.get()));
        }
    };
```

I'm usually reluctant to blame a compiler because it's usually my fault, but this time it really seems like they messed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I had originally:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Colony> colony_sptr;
std::unordered_set<colony_sptr> affected_colonies; // ERROR
```

And here's what "fixed" it:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Colony>> affected_colonies;
```

EDIT: This error disappeared after a VS restart, reappeared when I manually defined the type again and then switched back to the typedef, and has since disappeared again. I suspect this is either a very trippy bug or VS is mistaking errors in other parts of my code for some reason. I don't know enough / care enough to track this down. For now it seems to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: interesting... there's no difference with my Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop, both work (if Colony is `struct Colony {};`)

Comment: Well my typedef is in a #include'd file, and Colony is a rather large class, but I don't see why that would make a difference... very weird.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your version of MSVC doesn't support it, but there's a workaround that seems usable in the "Workarounds" tab on the page you linked.  Basically you just implement `std::hash` yourself for this type (on this compiler).

Comment: Well I'm using VC++11 as per the supposed solution so were those MS guys just talking rubbish then? I'll look into making a hash myself I suppose. <sigh>...

Comment: I think you've answered your own questions here.  :)

Comment: Ah crud when I try that hash function it says this: "1>c:\users\usr\code.h(282): error C2953: 'std::hash<std::shared_ptr<_Ty>>' : class template has already been defined". So... huh?

Comment: Any thoughts on trying the Boost versions of these types?

Comment: Well the standard one **should** work so I'd like to figure this out before I introduce a whole new library to my code (I've never used boost). But yeah I'll try that next. I've posted this over at MS support to see what they say (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a806ba8-a987-4da7-a70b-4fd6ac80589c/how-do-i-make-an-unorderedset-of-shared-pointers)